# Access ID from client to server side

Tags: asp.net, datetime, calendar, server, client-server

There is two calendars , one drop down and one grid view and button. Now i try to access these ID's on server side

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="regiondrop" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="regiondrop_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
 <input  ID="fromdate" value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
  <input  ID="todate" value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
<input type="button" id="search_data"    class="sear_btn"  value="Search Data"  />
```

and gridview

now i try to  display grid view on page

for this i try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {

         var fromdate = $('[ID*=fromdate]').val();
         var todate = $('[ID*=todate]').val();
         var regiondrop = $('[ID*=regiondrop] option:selected')[0].value;
         var GridView1 = $('[ID*=GridView1]');
         var obj = {};
         obj.fromdate = todate ;
         obj.todate = todate ;
         obj.regiondrop = regiondrop ;
         obj.GridView1 =GridView1 ;
         Getdataa(obj);
         return false;

 });
 function Getdataa(obj) {
     //alert('1');
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "WebForm1.aspx/search_data",
         data: "{'fromdate':'" + fromdate + "','todate':'" + todate + "','regiondrop':'" + regiondrop + "','GridView1':'" + GridView1 + "'}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         async: true,
         cache: false,
         success: function (result) {
             $("#GridView1").empty();
             if(data.d.length>0){
             $("#GridView1").append(
             "<tr><th>OName</th><th>RegNo</th>><th>Speed</th>");

             for(var i=0;i<data.d.length;i++){
             $("#GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + 
             data.d[i].OName + "</td> <td>" + 
             data.d[i].RegNo + "</td> <td>" + 
             data.d[i].Speed + "</td></tr>");
                }
            }   
         },
         error: function (error) {
             alert("error");

         }
     });
 }
```

For access ID's i try to get ID and then i pass these ID in webmethod function like ths

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string search_data(DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string regiondrop)
    {

        try
        {

            DateTime frmdate = 
           Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate.Value.Trim().Split('T')[0]);
            DateTime tdatee = 
            Convert.ToDateTime(todate.Value.Trim().Split('T')[0]);
            string regionvalue = Convert.ToString(regiondrop.SelectedValue);
            TrackDataEntities1 ts = new TrackDataEntities1();

            // here dq code is like this var dq= and here i write LINQ query  
            //i don't paste because of long query 
            GridView1.DataSource = dq;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            Label4.Text = ("No Data");

        }

    }
```

**UPDATE LINQ QUERY**

```
            var dq = (from vv in ts.tblVe
                      join rv in ts.tblRe on vv.ID equals rv.ID
                      join re in ts.tblReg on rv.RID equals re.RID
                      where
                      re.Region == regiondrop
                      && re.StartDate <= fromdate
                      && re.EndDate >= todate
                      orderby
                      vv.ID,
                      rv.OwnerName
                      select new
                      {
                          ID = vv.ID,
                          oname = rv.OName,
                          RegNo = rv.RegNo,
                          MaxSpeed = rv.Speed,


                      }).ToList();
```

when i try this show errors

Error   2   'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   3   'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   4   'string' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedValue' and no extension method 'SelectedValue' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   5   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'chart_project.WebForm1.GridView1'

Error   8   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'chart_project.WebForm1.Label4'

any solution

Comment: To access html id on server side you should use 
var date= Request.Form["fromdate"];

Comment: THIS SHow error ..Error 2 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Request.get'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no
>   extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

You are Passing `fromdate` as DateTime in your WebMethod so why you are treating it as a TextBox and trying to fetch the data using Value attribute and again converting it to DateTime. Same As for `todate`.

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedValue' and no
>   extension method 'SelectedValue' accepting a first argument of type
>   'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

For `regiondrop`, it's a string variable not a dropdownlist so you cannot use `SelectedValue` attribute for this.

So these Variable you could use directly.

> Error 5 An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'chart_project.WebForm1.GridView1'
>
> Error 8 An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'chart_project.WebForm1.Label4'

Gridview and Label are nonstatic fields, could not called in a static method. And you are binding your gridview in ajax on Success so why you need to bind it in WebMethod. Just return your dataset you want to bind with gridview and bind it in ajax method.

May Help you out [Reference Link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-Dataset-to-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx).

**Update**

```
    [WebMethod]
        public static string search_data(DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string regiondrop)
        {
           //Using your context
            var dq = (from vv in ts.tblVe
                          join rv in ts.tblRe on vv.ID equals rv.ID
                          join re in ts.tblReg on rv.RID equals re.RID
                          where
                          re.Region == regiondrop
                          && re.StartDate <= fromdate
                          && re.EndDate >= todate
                          orderby
                          vv.ID,
                          rv.OwnerName
                          select new
                          {
                              ID = vv.ID,
                              oname = rv.OName,
                              RegNo = rv.RegNo,
                              MaxSpeed = rv.Speed,


                          }).ToList();
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = 
                   new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            return jSearializer.Serialize(dq);
        }
```

Then in your Ajax method:

```
function Getdataa(obj) {
     //alert('1');
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "WebForm1.aspx/search_data",
         data: "{'fromdate':'" + fromdate + "','todate':'" + todate + "','regiondrop':'" + regiondrop + "'}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         async: true,
         cache: false,
         success: function (result) {
             $("#GridView1").empty();
             if(result.d.length>0){
             $("#GridView1").append(
             "<tr><th>OName</th><th>RegNo</th>><th>Speed</th>");

             for(var i=0;i<result.d.length;i++){
             $("#GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + 
             result.d[i].OName + "</td> <td>" + 
             result.d[i].RegNo + "</td> <td>" + 
             result.d[i].Speed + "</td></tr>");
                }
            } 
           else{
             $("#GridView1").hide();
             $("#Lable1").text("No Data");
           }  
         },
         error: function (error) {
             alert("error");

         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: so how i return dataset in linq?

Comment: Else return your list.

Comment: i try this ..  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                dq(ds);
                return ds;   but this show errors..* 'dq' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method' 
* Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'string'   @Rojalin Sahoo

Comment: ya, As per your code `var dq` it's a variable you could not use it like a method. so tried to return list as  `List<Class> Detail = new List<Class>();  return Detail;` . This may help you http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/775585/Bind-Gridview-using-AJAX

Comment: when i try this ..  List<WebForm1> detail=new List<WebForm1>();
                return detail;  this shows error .. Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<chart_project.WebForm1>' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: If dq is a JSON data then directly return dq to ajax method and I saw you written code to bind gridview with the result data. Only one thing to handle is use same parameter name that you passed in `success: function (result)`.

Comment: where i passed this parameter name ? and how i directly return dq to ajax?

Comment: in dq data is like this... [0] = { ID = 1, OName = "Khan", RegNo = "AJ-24",Speed = "124" }
[1] = { ID = 2, OName = "Shah", RegNo = "AL-91",Speed = "95" }

Comment: Could you post your linq query?

Comment: please check update question .. section update linq query

Comment: when i try your update then this show error on LIst  which you write after static .. Error 3 Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: You could add Model name of your returning query like `List<ModelName>` or else convert  result to json as updated.

Comment: but my result are already in json like this [0] = { ID = 1, OName = "Khan", RegNo = "AJ-24",Speed = "124" } [1] = { ID = 2, OName = "Shah", RegNo = "AL-91",Speed = "95" } i think ???????????

Comment: and i try you update but grid-view not display also there is no error..

Comment: tried to debug with break-point, that values are coming or not?

Comment: i user asp gridview